# Multiple user types and ratings in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm making a DRF backend with three user types: customer, personal trainer and gym owner. I want all the fields in the CustomUser class to apply to each user type. I also want some specific attributes to each user type (for example photo only for personal trainer and gym owner). Is this the right way to do it?

```
# models.py

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('customer'),
        ('personal_trainer'),
        ('gym_owner'),
    )

    user_type = models.CharField(blank=False, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    ratings = models.ForeignKey(Rating, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)


class PersonalTrainer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)


class GymOwner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

I also have a ratings model. I want to be able to leave a rating as a customer to a personal trainer or a gym. Each rating will have a one to one relation with it's owner and it's target. I'm not sure however how I can make the relations..?

```
# models.py

class Rating(models.Model):
    STAR_CONVERSION = (
        (1, 'One Star'),
        (2, 'Two Stars'),
        (3, 'Three Stars'),
        (4, 'Four Stars'),
        (5, 'Five Stars'),
    )

    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STAR_CONVERSION)
    caption = models.TextField(blank=True)

    owner = models.OneToOneField(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # I want a target as a one to one relation to either PersonalTrainer or GymOwner
    target = models.OneToOneField(*either personal trainer or gym owner*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make both `owner` and `target` a `ForeignKey` rather than a `OneToOneField`. With the latter, you could only have one rating for every customer and one for every provider, which would be a bit restrictive :).

For `PersonalTrainer` and `GymOwner`, you need model inheritance. The parent model would either be an abstract class (with the data saved in the tables of the individual child models), or (preferably in this case as the fields of both models are the same) the data would be saved in the parent model (e.g. `Provider`), while the child models would be [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) based on the parent model's data, but providing different behaviour where appropriate.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) have quite a lot to say about the different inheritance options.

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)

class PersonalTrainer(Provider):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class GymOwner(Provider):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Rating(models.Model):   
    # ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: With `owner` and `target` being FK fields, one might need to think about introducing some `unique_together` constraint as well. Unless it is desired to allow the same customer to "review-bomb" the same provider, that is. Even if the rating would be tied to a date or a specific course additionally, I feel like allowing more that one rating per customer, provider and context sounds wrong.

Comment: @shmee That's an important consideration, yes. If you only want one review per customer/provider pair, a `unique_together` is sufficient; for other constraints (e.g. one review within a certain time, etc.), you either need Python code or additional model fields.